# How to find out whether a location is open at a future date and time using HTTP request

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I'd like to get something like isOpen([date]) function result using a HTTP request to obtain information whether a location is open at a certain date&time in the future. Can that work and if yes, how? Here's an example-request I'm using and would like to extend:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJqXBlNgBSqEcRGDZOTvIdl4Q&fields=name,opening_hours/periods&key=

When I try to use this it generates an error "Unsupported field name 'isOpen' as isOpen() is not a field but a function :( ):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJqXBlNgBSqEcRGDZOTvIdl4Q&fields=name,opening_hours/isOpen()&key=.

any hint would be highly appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your request generates a `Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'isOpen'.`  because there's no `isOpen` field under `opening_hours`. You can use the `open_now` instead to return a boolean value whether the place is open at the current time.  Here's a sample request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJqXBlNgBSqEcRGDZOTvIdl4Q&fields=name,opening_hours/open_now&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can also use the `periods/open` to return the time the place is open.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJqXBlNgBSqEcRGDZOTvIdl4Q&fields=name,opening_hours/open_now,opening_hours/periods/open&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can learn more about the fields returned by Place Details [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults).

Comment: Thank you for the response @Pagemag! I guess there is no solution for the isOpen() method as HTTP request and I have to code a wrapper around the json-file I'm receiving as a result...